# Как правильно удалить компонент в дизайнере

Tags: delphi-7, компоненты, vcl

У меня панель `TPanel` в неё добавляются в дизайнере другие панели и вносятся во внутренний список. Но при удалении внутренних панелей не пойму как удалить из внутреннего списка. 
При добавлении пользуюсь редактором

```
procedure TShiftPanelEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
var
  zPanel: TPanelEx;
begin
  case Index of
    0:
      begin
        zPanel := Designer.CreateComponent(TPanelEx, Component, -1, -1, -1, -1) as TPanelEx;
        zPanel.ShiftingPanel := (Component as TShiftingPanel);
      end;
      else inherited;
  end;
end;
```

По своству zPanel.ShiftingPanel определен сеттер который вставляет панель во внутренний список

```
procedure TPanelEx.SetPanel(const Value: TShiftingPanel);
begin
  Value.InsertPanel(Self);

end;
```

Как организовать правильно удаление?

Comment: сохраняется ли установленный `TShiftingPanel` в `TPanelEx` как приватное поле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует более общий и (на мой взгляд) более изящный способ отслеживания удаления вложенных контролов. Ко всему прочему - он позволяет поддерживать в актуальном состоянии внутренний список не только при высвобождении объекта, но и при изменении его родителя (к примеру, если вложенная панель перемещается на другую `TShiftingPanel`):

```pascal
type
  TShiftingPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    FPanels: TList;
    procedure CMControlChange(var Message: TMessage); message CM_CONTROLCHANGE;
  end;

procedure TShiftingPanel.CMControlChange(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  // обрабатываем сообщение о том, что нам "внутрь" пытаются добавить
  // или удалить компонент
  // через установку свойства Parent.
  // это же сообщение отправляется при удалении вложенного компонента
  // т.к. при его уничтожении выставляется Parent = nil.
  if TObject(message.WParam) is TPanelEx then
    if Boolean(message.LParam) then
      begin
        // контрол добавляется
        FPanels.Add(Pointer(message.WParam));
      end
    else
      begin
        // контрол удаляется
        FPanels.Remove(Pointer(message.LParam));
      end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Таким образом отпадает необходимость во внешнем отслеживании актуальности списка `FPanels` - сама `TShiftingPanel` будет следить за этим. А вложенным панелям останется только выставлять свойство `Parent`.

---

Кроме того, предлагаю избавиться от свойства `TPanelEx.ShiftingPanel`. Вернее, не избавиться, а оставить только getter. Если я правильно понимаю, то `ShiftingPanel` должна возвращать панель, на которой лежит `PanelEx`. А это уже известно из свойства `Parent`:

```pascal
TPanelEx = class(TPanel)
public
  property ShiftingPanel: TShiftingPanel read GetShiftingPanel;
end;

function TPanelEx.GetShiftingPanel: TShiftingPanel;
begin
  if Parent is TShiftingPanel then
    Result:=TShiftingPanel(Parent)
  else
    Result:=nil;
end;
```

Comment: Пытаюсь переделать под ваш вариант , но в функции `TShiftPanelEditor.ExecuteVerb` редактора вылетает ошибка о том что не найдена точка входа в процедуру `ShiftingPanel` вот на этой строке  `zShiftinfPanel := TPanelEx(Component).ShiftingPanel`. Сообщение об ошибке вылетает когда пытаюсь установить компонент по `install` . `ShiftingPanel` - свойство с геттером из вашего варианта

Comment: Как везде пишут, что `ExecuteVerb` вызывается по щелчку мыши на меню этого компонента, то тогда почему там вываливается ошибка? если закомментить тело, то ошибка не возникает при `install`

Comment: Теоретически, сообщение должно быть не таким (приведите полный текст) - ведь `ShiftingPanel` это не процедура, а свойство у которого есть только геттер. Кстати, вы не забыли объявить геттер как приватную функцию объекта? Не уверен, что автоматизация существует в D7, однако если поставить курсор в тело функции `GetShiftingPanel` и нажать `Ctrl + Shift+C`, объявление должно автоматически перекочевать в объявление класса в `private`-секцию. Или же - поставить курсор внутрь объявления `TPanelEx` и нажать ту же комбинацию клавиш.

Comment: В догонку - с CM_CONTROLCHANGE получилось? У меня были большие сомнения по поводу наличия такого функционала в D7, хотя в линейке D2010 - XE7 он просуществовал без изменений.

Comment: С CM_CONTROLCHANGE вроде получилось. [Вот код ошибки](http://s45.radikal.ru/i108/1603/4c/45218309ca11.png)  .Процедура `GetShiftingPanel` есть и он в секции  private. могу ли я привести полный код как нибудь ?

Comment: @gregor, формат Stackoverflow, к сожалению (а скорее - к счастью) не предусматривает решение вопросов в комментариях. Тем более, что вопрос вы решили самостоятельно, задолго до моего ответа. И возникшая проблема напрямую не относится к исходному вопросу, это было всего лишь мое предложение для уменьшения полей в создаваемых классах. Предлагаю дальнейшее обсуждение перенести в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37246/discussion-between-kami-and-gregor

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37247/discussion-between-gregor-and-kami).

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим образом

```
procedure TShiftPanelEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
var
  zPanel: TPanelEx;
  zShiftinfPanel: TShiftingPanel;
begin
  if Component is TShiftingPanel then
    zShiftinfPanel := TShiftingPanel(Component)
  else
    if Component is TPanelEx then
      zShiftinfPanel := TPanelEx(Component).ShiftingPanel
      else raise Exception.Create('Component is not TPanelEx');
   case Index of
    0:
      begin
         zPanel := TPanelEx.Create((Designer).GetRoot);
         zPanel.Parent := zShiftinfPanel;
         zPanel.ShiftingPanel := zShiftinfPanel;
         Designer.SelectComponent(zPanel);
         Designer.Modified;
       end;
     1:  if Component is TPanelEx then TPanelEx(Component).Free;
  end;
end;

function TShiftPanelEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  case Index of
    0: Result := 'New panel';
    1: Result := 'Delete panel';
  end;
end;
```

в деструкторе `TPanelEx`

```
destructor TPanelEx.Destroy;
begin
  if FShiftingPanel <> nil then
    FShiftingPanel.RemovePanel(Self);

  inherited;
end
```

а уже в `FShiftingPanel.RemovePanel(Self);`

```
procedure TShiftingPanel.RemovePanel(aPanel: TPanelEx);
begin
  aPanel.ShiftingPanel := nil;
  FPanels.Remove(aPanel);
end;
```